# windows communication between two applications

Tags: arm, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I want to create two applications running on the same device (windows rt).
One application would be the app for inputting strings (example is string "235").
The second application would be the output for the first application. (showing "235").
Is it possible to do this in visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible to do in Visual Studio and to run on a development machine using the loopback adapter, however the loopback adapter is disabled for release builds. You can use the share contract to share your content as a custom object that only your intended application knows how to consume as a share target to accomplish this.  A little more about your scenario is needed to provide proper guidance.

John Wiese
Microsoft - Sr. Technical Evangelist
jwiese@microsoft.com
@johnwiese

Comment: Basically I created an app that displays a number entered. I want to create another app which shows the displayed number from the first app. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: there is no easy way to do this in a WinRT as applications are designed to be sandboxed and communicate via approved mechanisms (charms).  You could write the value to a file in the documents library and then read it periodically from the other app.  Or you would have the app post the changed value to a service and have the second app periodically check the service for the current value.  Those are the only options you really have.

Comment: thank s for helping me out. This is off topic but would it be possible to create this idea as a single program with 2 windows? One window would be keypad. While the other window would be the output number entered? Can I create this program in visual studio?

Comment: If you are going that far then I would use the share charm and create your own object to share.  Have the first app be a share source that shares the object with the number in it and have your display app be a share target that understands the custom object being shared and displays the info.  Check here, specifically the "Choosing Data Formats for Sharing" link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758314.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using DLL files.
More info: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/815065